# Css Animation Keyframes Doesn't start when tab out

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a css animation that basically starts only after 10 seconds. However, sometimes, if I'm on another tab before the animation starts and I stay on that tab, the animation starts only when I return to the tab / page that has the animation.

```js
document.getElementById('CircleTimer').getElementsByTagName('circle')[0].style.animation = ' countdown 10s linear infinite';
```

```css
#CircleTimer circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 200px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: #04e004;
  fill: none;
}

@keyframes countdown {
  from {
    stroke: #04e004;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
  to {
    stroke: #dd0000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="CircleTimer">
  <circle r="31" cx="35" cy="35"></circle>
  <span id="CountDown">10</span>
</svg>
```

Comment: Well, browsers pause or slow down such stuff for inactive tabs, for performance reasons ...

Comment: Just sometimes, or always? Happening sometimes would be strange.

Comment: Really quick answer!

Basically, There's nothing I can do?

Not always, but frequently.

Comment: I guess not, this is a common practice in pages as bitly etc. Where u need to be on that tab in order to continue with the countdown. Maybe theres some code to force, I really dont know.

Comment: DId you mean.. starts after 10 seconds or stops after 10 seconds? Because this animation doesn't start after 10 seconds

Comment: Starts after 10 seconds...

Basically, I have a function that starts the animation 10 seconds after someone has been connected.

Comment: I don't really see any animation starting after 10 seconds, though.

Comment: Basically, I have a setInterval in a function that use document.getElementById('CircleTimer').getElementsByTagName('circle')[0].style.animation = ' countdown 10s linear infinite';

But, I thought it wasn't important to copy and paste a whole function, since if I'm on the current tab the animation starts as it should.

Comment: SO.. what's the point of the JS? You can get the same effect without the Js. The animation you do is basically a countdown. Animation starts and it finishes in 10 seconds. If a second animation happens AFTER those 10 seconds, please provide that code aswell

Comment: However, the animation needs to starts at a certain moment and stop at a certain moment and restart later. If you know a way to do it without JS I'm all open.

It's all about document.getElementById('CircleTimer').getElementsByTagName(‌​'circle')[0].style.a‌​nimation = ' countdown 10s linear infinite';

However, I use it in a different moments like right after someone is connected then the timer run 10 times in a row then stop until someone else is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I'm pretty sure now that the issue is with :

```js
document.getElementById('CircleTimer').getElementsByTagName('circle')[0].style.animation = ' countdown 10s linear infinite';
```

It seems to not give those properties until I'm on the page.
I made a Jsfiddle to give you an example.

https://jsfiddle.net/8L8vfjsg/

Comment: Update:

I added : 
  var d = new Date();
  var date = d.getMinutes();
  console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('Test')[0] + date);
  console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('TestAnimation')[0] + date);

Basically, the div get the new class from the javascript. However, the animation doesn't start if I'm not on the page. I can't figure out a way to solve it.